# How not to have to type "bundle exec" using Bundler binstubs & chruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, bundle, zsh, chruby

I'm using chruby to manage my Ruby versions, and Bundler's binstubs to avoid having to type "bundle exec". I'm running into issues I don't totally understand. Here's what I get when I try to run the test suite in our (Rails 4, Ruby 2.2.2) application:

```
$ rspec             
/Users/duncanmalashock/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- simplecov (LoadError)
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/ruby_projects/platform/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/ruby_projects/platform/spec/controllers/admin/admin_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/duncanmalashock/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

When I run `$ bundle exec rspec`, the suite runs correctly. I've been looking into postmodern's [gem_home](https://github.com/postmodern/gem_home), and have installed it, but it's not giving me the results I'm looking for. I'm using zsh on OSX Yosemite.

in .zshrc:

```
source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source '/usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh'
source /usr/local/share/gem_home/gem_home.sh

export PATH=./.bundle/bin:$PATH
alias b='bundle install --path .bundle/gems --binstubs .bundle/bin'
```

Comment: Duncan, did my answer help? Please let me know if you have any other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the `simplecov` gem in your system (simply do: `gem install simplecov`) and run your test again. It will work.

But, it's a better practice to use `bundle exec` to run the rake or rspec commands. Because that way, you would ensure that the command is running in the context of your `Gemfile`.

You can add these aliases to your `.zshrc` file:

```
alias ber="bundle exec rspec"
alias be="bundle exec"
```

And, then run your rspec tests like this:

```
ber
```

or,

```
be rspec
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that bundler has installed `simplecov` local to the project and you are trying to run the system global `rspec`.  That is going to look for `simplecov` in the system ruby library location.  Using a Ruby language version manager is not going to change this behaviour.  It will just use the versioned ruby's library location instead.

If you wish your versioned Ruby to use `rspec` and `simplecov` together then you need to install `simplecov` in your versioned ruby using whatever tool equivalent to `gem` that is provided.

I am not sure why you find running `bundle exec` of great import.  One can always create an alias in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.  I have two for bundle exec, one is `be` and the other `bexec`.  I also have aliases for `bundle exec rails` (`brails`) and `bundle exec rake` (`break`). In practice I find that these are really little different than running the customary commands.